# Regex pattern to NOT match string begining with space

Tags: regex

I'm fiddling around with regex trying to understand how patterns work but I can't seem to get it right.

I am testing a string of numbers. The idea is that the test should only return true for strings consisting of solely this: optional part (digit "9" followed or not by space) and required part (any three digits).
So the strings like "345" "9345" and "9 345" should return true and strings like "99345" "9 345"(it's meant to be double space here, the automatic styling keeps condensing it to one space) " 345" "45" or "3456" should return false.

The closest to the desired result I got was with regex pattern `/^[9]?[ ]?\d{3}$/` that almost fits but still returns true for string " 345".

I've tried to go from here and modify pattern to this `/^[9]?[(?<=9) ]?\d{3}$/` so the space matches only if it is preceded by 9 but it doesn't seem to work, the results are same as for previous pattern. Then I tried this `/^[9|9 ]?\d{3}$/` to imply that the string may or may not begin with either "9" or "9 " but that still returns true for " 345" and also starts returning false for "9 345" for some reason.

I also tried this version `/^[^ ]^[9]?[ ]?\d{3}$/` and `/^[^\s]^[9]?[ ]?\d{3}$/` and this `/^[\S]^[9]?[ ]?\d{3}$/` to imply the string cannot begin with space (or whitespace per se) but that only seems to ruin everything as nothing matches true then.

I'm out of ideas now so any hints and advices are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the pattern optionally matching a 9 followed by an optional space:

```
^(?:9 ?)?\d{3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cgxmif/1)

---

If you want to make the 0 and the 9 both optional and you want to  use lookarounds (which you don't have to because the optional group also suffices):

Assert that the string does not start with a space after the match using a [lookbehind](https://regex101.com/r/wcHHa1/1)

```
^[9]? ?(?<!^ )\d{3}$
```

Assert that the string does not start with a space using a [lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/727kjO/1)

```
^(?! )9? ?\d{3}$
```

Comment: Next complicated possibility: Use if then else `^(9)?(?(1) |)?\d{3}$?` ([see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tUHhsv/1))

Answer (score 1):

Does the regex `^(9 |9)?\d{3}$` work ?
I personnaly use https://regexr.com to build my regex. The tests part allows you to enter what must pass and what must fail the regex